# Why is this summation equal to ...

Tags: summation

I have this equation

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }j(j+1)c_{j+1}\varrho ^{j}+2(L+1)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }(j+1)c_{j+1}\varrho ^{j}-2\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }jc_{j}\varrho ^{j} +(\varrho_0-2(L+1))\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }c_j\varrho ^j=0$

and I can't see, why it should imply

$j(j+1)c_{j+1}+2(L+1)(j+1)c_{j+1}-2jc_j+\left [\varrho_0-2(L+1) \right ]c_j=0$

I only know, that you can divide the first equation with $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }\varrho ^{j}$ to remove all the $\varrho ^{j}$.

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }j(j+1)c_{j+1}+2(L+1)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }(j+1)c_{j+1}-2\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }jc_{j} +(\varrho_0-2(L+1))\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }c_j=0$

Comment: If  $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}A_jx^j=0$ for all real $x\in (a,b)$ with $a<b$ then for all $j$ we have $A_j=0$.

Comment: I can't see, why that should be usefull?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the first expression comes from a differential equation for which the solution is expressed as a series.

Since the expression must be true for any degree $j$, the second expression just corresponds to the same for this specific degree. Manipulating it, it gives the recurrence relation between the coefficients $c_{j+1}$ and $c_j$.

My only concern is : what is $\varrho_0$ ?

Answer (score 2):

All four sums are from $0$ to $\infty$, hence you can write it as one sum \begin{align*}&\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}j(j+1)c_{j+1}+2(L+1)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1)c_{j+1}-2\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}jc_j+(q_0-2(L+1))\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}c_j \\ &=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1)[j+2(L+1)]c_{j+1}-[2j+2(L+1)-q_0]c_j=0\end{align*}Now, as suggested in comments, if $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i x^i=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_i x^i$ then $\forall 0\le i<\infty: \ a_i=b_i$.